# How can i get campaign's web id when campaign is created using API in Mailchimp?

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I am using API version 1.3 of mailchimp to create Campaign programmatically in PHP.

I am using `MCAPI` class method `campaignCreate()` to create campaign. Campaign is created successfully and it returns campaign id in response which is string.

But i need Web id (integer value of campaign id) so that I can use it to open that campaign using link on my website.

For example: lets say I want to redirect user to this link - https://us8.admin.mailchimp.com/campaigns/show?id=941117  and for that i need id value as 941117 when new campaign is created.For now i am getting it as string like 6ae9ikag when new campaign is created using mailchimp API

Please let me know if anyone knows how to get campaign web id (integer value) using Mailchimp API in PHP

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer so wanted to share here.Hope it helps someone

I get campaign id as a string when createCampaign() method of MCAPI class is used.

You need to use below code to get web id (integer value of campaign id)

```
$filters['campaign_id'] = $campaign_id;  // string value of campaign id
$campaign = $api->campaigns($filters);
$web_id = $campaign['data'][0]['web_id'];
```

This worked for me.

Thanks

Comment: web_id isn't returned with api v3. How can we obtain that info with version 3? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
/**
This Example shows how to create a basic campaign via the MCAPI class.
**/
require_once 'inc/MCAPI.class.php';
require_once 'inc/config.inc.php'; //contains apikey

$api = new MCAPI($apikey);

$type = 'regular';

$opts['list_id'] = '5ceacbda08';
$opts['subject'] = 'Test Newsletter Mail';
$opts['from_email'] = 'guna@test.com'; 
$opts['from_name'] = 'guna';

$opts['tracking']=array('opens' => true, 'html_clicks' => true, 'text_clicks' => false);

$opts['authenticate'] = true;
$opts['analytics'] = array('google'=>'my_google_analytics_key');
$opts['title'] = 'Test Newsletter Title';

$content = array('html'=>'Hello html content message', 
    'text' => 'text text text *|UNSUB|*'
  );

$retval = $api->campaignCreate($type, $opts, $content);


if ($api->errorCode){
 echo "Unable to Create New Campaign!";
 echo "\n\tCode=".$api->errorCode;
 echo "\n\tMsg=".$api->errorMessage."\n";
} else {
 echo "New Campaign ID:".$retval."\n";
}

$retval = $api->campaignSendNow($retval);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The web_id is returned by mailchimp when a call is made to the creation end point.

```
$mcResponce = $mailchimp_api->campaigns->create(...);
$web_id = $mcResponce['web_id'];
```

See the [documentation](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/list.php).